# Adding CSS class to form element in Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I create forms in Moodle by extending the moodle `moodleform` class and calling the `addElement()` or `createElement()` methods. For example, I create a select element this way:

```
$mform->addElement('select', 'mySelect',  'Select title' , $list);
```

Where `$mform` is a reference to the form, and `$list` is an associative array like:

`$list = array('1'=>'one', '2'=>'two', '3'=>'three')`.

The question is: Is there a way to add a CSS class associated with this or other form elements?

I other words, I would like to programmatically add a class `myClass`, so that the HTML code looks like this:

```
<select class="myClass">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the 5th addElement parameter - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/formslib.php_Form_Definition#select

```
$mform->addElement('select', 'myselect', 'Select title', $list, ['class' => 'myclass']);
```

(And I assume your real code does this correctly, but make sure you use get_string() for param 3, so it can be translated).

Comment: Your assumption is right, I use get_string() in the real code;-)